# Flag to disable 'Cookies without SameSite must be secure' when launching chrome

Tags: samesite

I need to launch chrome with 'Cookies without SameSite must be secure' turned off for our automated test suite. We're already using the `--disable-web-security` flag but that does not work. I also tried different permutations of `--disable-features=same-site-by-default-cookies` but I don't seem to have the feature name correct. What flag to I need to add to chrome launcher to ensure this is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I entered issue [1126989](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1126989) to see if this can be included under `--disable-web-security`. The correct syntax was provided as `--disable-features=CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure`